# Error: Join in MySql, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables in mysql one is quote and the fields are quote_id, status, created and submit_by. in submit_by field i am saving username of the employee and in employee table the fields are firs_name, last_name, username, password. I want to show in a php table the employee first name instead of username of the employee.

**full quote table stucture**

[image]

**full employee table sructure**

[image]

this is the code i am using but not getting any result

```
$sql = "SELECT q.quote_id, q.client_name, q.status, e.first_name 
        FROM `quote` AS q 
        LEFT JOIN `employee` AS e ON q.submit_by = e.username";
```

Comment: Can you post the table structure.?

Comment: how to post the table structure ?

Comment: Edit your question and post the schema

Comment: Can you add some input data to understand why your query isn't working?

Comment: not getting any output @almasshaikh

Comment: Run the queries ``EXPLAIN quote;`` and ``EXPLAIN employee;`` in MySQL and that will give you the structure of the tables. Paste those tables.

Comment: @IamRsdfan Take a screenshot from phpmyadmin

Comment: table structure posted , please check.thanks  @ub3rst4r

Comment: Is there any content in quote table?

Comment: @IamRsdfan:try my query and let me know,if it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one

```
$sql = "SELECT * , employee.first_name FROM quote 
LEFT JOIN employee ON quote.submit_by = employee.username ORDER BY quote.client_name";
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

> try this:

```
 SELECT quote.quote_id, quote.client_name, quote.status, employee.first_name FROM quote 
    LEFT JOIN employee ON quote.submit_by = employee.username ORDER BY quote.client_name;
```

Comment: @IamRsdfan: if it is useful for you,so please upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Query to get the result.

```
SELECT q.`quote_id`, q.`client_name`, q.`status`, e.`first_name` FROM `quote` q , `employee` e WHERE q.`submit_by` = e.`username`;
```